# When to use HTML section or article tag for a good semantic structure

Tags: html, semantics, semantic-markup

I have the following structure and content on a specific page:

```
<header>
// Logo
// Site navigation
</header>
<main>
 <article>
  <section>
  // Hero image or video block
  </section>
  <section>
  // Here all kinds of paragraphs are rendered (e.g: Call to action, related video's block to this page, related actors block related to this page etc.
 // All those blocks has their own <section> tag  
  </section>
 </article>
</main>
```

So in above example inside `<article>` I have 2 `<section>` tags and then inside the second `<section>` I have more `<section>` tags nested. Is this correct approach?

Comment: nesting section elements is totally acceptable, however you need to just make sure it makes sense to do so.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Typically, the `article` tag would be used on blog pages, either for a collection of several blog articles on one page (i.e. containing several `<article>` tags), or for a single article page (i.e. containing *one* `<article>` tag). In any case, an article should stand on its own thematically, its understanding not depending on anything else outside the article tag.

`<section>`s are similar, but are rather used to cover several aspects of the general subject treated on the particular page (also inside an article). There are cases where those two can be interchageable, but in general interpreting the word "article" literally can help IMO.

Comment: thanks what do you mean exactly with: _either for a collection of several blog articles on one page_. Do you have an example?

Comment: That's ANY blog start page that lists blog articles - there are millions of them.